# I just want to put some texts between tags using appendchild methods with Javascript

Tags: javascript

This code below is a javascript code to change texts and background properties from the body tag at the same time when the browser is clicked. I've just followed rules in w3school.com, actually, I'm doing the same as the examples do, but mine won't work and I've failed to find my fault. plz, help me.

```
var helloDiv = document.createElement("div");
var helloText = document.createTextNode("hi.");
helloDiv.appendChild(helloText);
var bodyntext = document.getElementsByTagName("body").appendChild(helloDiv);
var complementary = new Array();
var j = 0;

window.onclick = function(){

    var background_color; 
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    // var color = new Array();
    var result = null;

    var number = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);
    for(var i = 0; i > 3; i++)
    {
        complementary[i] = (255-(number.slice(j,j+1).toString(10))).toString(16);
        j = j + 2;
    }

    var clnumber = (complementary[0]+complementary[1]+complementary[2]).toString(16);

    body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+ number.toString();
    bodyntext.style.color = "#"+ clnumber.toString();


}
```

Comment: Explain why it is not working. Open the browser's console (right click -> inspect -> console tab on chromium) to check the error being thrown and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] to achieve expected result, as getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.

```js
var helloDiv = document.createElement("div");
var helloText = document.createTextNode("hi.");
helloDiv.appendChild(helloText);
var bodyntext = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(helloDiv);
var complementary = new Array();
var j = 0;

window.onclick = function(){

    var background_color; 
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    // var color = new Array();
    var result = null;

    var number = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);
    for(var i = 0; i > 3; i++)
    {
    complementary[i] = (255-(number.slice(j,j+1).toString(10))).toString(16);
        j = j + 2;
    }

    var clnumber = (complementary[0]+complementary[1]+complementary[2]).toString(16);

    body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+ number.toString();
    bodyntext.style.color = "#"+ clnumber.toString();


}
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NLBXJE
Please refer this link for more details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: thank you so much. but it also won't work. actually I think losing '[0]' was one of mistakes to happen while I tried to fix it. I used to use 'body' instead of 'getElementsByTagName("body")[0]' as like the site I learn from. so, mind if i ask you to check an example this link? (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createelement4)

Comment: I'm sorry to reply late. I fell asleep before I saw your answer. Yes, it's working now! I really appreciate your help. It's help me a lot :)

Comment: Glad it is working , If my post solved your issue, can you mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I just change **appendChild** to **document.body.appendChild(helloDiv)** and added **ID** attribute for that div:

```js
var helloDiv = document.createElement("div");
    helloDiv.id = "myDIV";
document.body.appendChild(helloDiv);

var helloText = document.createTextNode("Click me");
helloDiv.appendChild(helloText);

var complementary = new Array();
var j = 0;

window.onclick = function(){

    var background_color; 
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var helloText = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    // var color = new Array();
    var result = null;

    var number = Math.round(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);
    for(var i = 0; i > 3; i++)
    {
    complementary[i] = (255-(number.slice(j,j+1).toString(10))).toString(16);
        j = j + 2;
    }

    var clnumber = (complementary[6]+complementary[1]+complementary[2]).toString(16);
    var clnumber2 = (complementary[0]+complementary[2]+complementary[6]).toString(11);
    
    body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+ number.toString();
    helloText.style.color = "#"+number.toString();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem

> var bodyntext = document.getElementsByTagName("body").appendChild(helloDiv);

Please note that the javascript functions that have plural names often return arrays which is the case here

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")` returns an array and you are trying to perform an invalid action, that is append child, to this array. You need to access an element using index and then perform this action.

so using
`var bodyntext = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(helloDiv);` should fix your problem.